How to use javascript libraries like PDF.js from MAUI Blazor WASM Windows app?
I am trying to use the PDF.js library in a .NET 8 MAUI Blazor WebAssembly app for Windows, in JS isolation fashion.
Custom pdfLoader.js file:
import * as pdfjsLib from './pdfjs/pdf.mjs';

export function loadPdf() {
    ... code with pdfjsLib ...
}

Importing pdfLoader.js:
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        // Error in this line:
        _module = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
            "import",
            "./pdfLoader.js");

        await _module.InvokeVoidAsync("loadPdf");
    }
}

Error:

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but
the server responded with a MIME type of "application/octet-stream".
Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML
spec. blazor.webview.js:1  Failed to fetch dynamically imported
module: https://0.0.0.0/pdfLoader.js TypeError: Failed to fetch
dynamically imported module: https://0.0.0.0/pdfLoader.js    at
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64
targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)    at
MyApp.Components.Pages.Book.OnAfterRenderAsync(Boolean firstRender)
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task
taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)

I get this error only when debugging the app on Windows, if I USB debug on Android I don't get errors when importing PDF.js but only when invoking the loadPdf custom javascript function.
// No error here on Android:
_module = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
    "import",
    "./pdfLoader.js");

// But error here on Android:
await _module.InvokeVoidAsync("loadPdf"); 

Still got to check what error is reported when invoking loadPdf, because I don't know how to visualize the JS errors on Android, but most likely it's just a mistake in the implementation.
I also found the importing error in a blazor library that makes use of PDF.js, but based on my research (will include the link here), it only happens when running blazor WASM apps on Windows in contrast to other operating systems or blazor web apps. I reported a bug specific to Windows and WASM for this Blazor library that uses PDF.js:
https://github.com/vikramlearning/blazorbootstrap/issues/719#issuecomment-2118683667

I probably could get it working, just don’t have time right now. I’ve used the pdfdist before. I might recommend parsing the pdf binary into base64 encode and trying that which is usually easier.

@lastlink Pretty sure that the error refers about the encoding of the javascript module and not the encoding of the PDF document.
